# Firefox Django CSRF token error

Tags: django, firefox, csrf

I recently made some changes to a form to do some more advanced error checking than celery provides (errors based on input from multiple fields).  Everything was working fine until a coworker found that the form didn't work on Firefox anymore (dev and testing done on Chrome).

The specific error being thrown is:

`django.request [WARNING] > Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /[url]`

I suspect the root of this issue comes from the change:

`<form action="{% url '[submit url]' %}">` to
`<form onsubmit="sendData()">` where `sendData` constructs an `XMLHttpRequest` and sends it.  I've tried adding `csrftoken` header to the request from `{{csrf_token}}` but it fails for the same reason - and even breaks the process on Chrome!

Answer (score 1):

The csrf_token should be in your XMLHttpRequest not in the form since you are using JS to send data:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", "{{ csrf_token }}");
xhttp.send();
```